# Unable to run dataflow pipeline in DataflowRunner mode

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I run a simple test dataflow pipeline in GCP using DirectRunner and it is ok. But when I try with DataFlowRunner, I believe that the worker try to install apache-beam and it cannot due to proxy access.
My goal is to run the pipeline on Google Dataflow. I had the impression that DataFlow should take care of having apache-beam pre-installed on worker. Shall I use a container with all requirements?
I appreciate any suggestions.

```
python3 pipeline.py \
  --project='....' \
  --region='....' \
  --service_account_email='....' \
  --dataset_id='dset_name' \
  --ingest_table_name='table_name' \
  --storage_bucket='....' \
  --temp_location='....' \
  --runner=DataFlowRunner

INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Downloading source distribution of the SDK from PyPi
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.stager:Executing command: ['/opt/conda/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', 'download', '--dest', '/var/tmp/tmp3ajs7rn0', 'apache-beam==2.45.0', '--no-deps', '--no-binary', ':all:']
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4f67e52ed0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))': /simple/apache-beam/
......
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache-beam==2.45.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache-beam==2.45.0
```

==== update ===
I tried to use a docker image:

```
options.view_as(WorkerOptions).worker_harness_container_image = '...apache/beam_python3.7_sdk'
```

and I get the error: "Pip install failed for package: apache-beam==2.45.0
Output from execution of subprocess: b"Collecting apache-beam==2.45.0\n  Using cached apache-beam-2.45.0.zip (3.0 MB)\n  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started\n  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'\n"

So it will be helpful to know the correct syntax for using a container image with DataFlow pipelines.

==update==
I created a virtual env and installed wheel and apache-beam[gcp]
Now I receive a different and very strange error. No matter which unique name I use for the job_name, the error is:
"`apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient.DataflowJobAlreadyExistsError: There is already active job named pipeline_unique_name with id: ppline_unique_id. If you want to submit a second job, try again by setting a different name using --job_name.`"

Answer (score 0):

`--runner=DataFlowRunner` explicitly specifies to run the code on the Google Cloud Platform,

To run locally, **try removing this parameter**

see [apache beam's doc](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/#windowedwordcount-example)

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.windowed_wordcount --input YOUR_INPUT_FILE --output_table PROJECT:DATASET.TABLE
```

If you want to run the pipeline on Dataflow, you need to [set up your environment](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-python?get-the-apache-beam-sdk#set-up-your-environment)

Get the correct version of `python`, `pip`. I suggest you to use a `virtualenv`.

It's also important to install `wheel` then get `apache-beam` along with `[gcp]`.

```
pip install wheel
pip install 'apache-beam[gcp]'
```

When everything is set up, try running the example in Dataflow using the following :

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
    --region DATAFLOW_REGION \
    --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt \
    --output gs://STORAGE_BUCKET/results/outputs \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project PROJECT_ID \
    --temp_location gs://STORAGE_BUCKET/tmp/
```

Comment: Yes, I was saying that when I run it on VM in GCP ('locally') with DirectRunner it is ok. 
The problem is that when I try to run it using DataflowRunner it doesn't find the apache-beam. Is there other solution than to specify a container ?

Comment: @crbl did you install `apache-beam[gcp]` ? I edidted my answer

Comment: From your question "did you install apache-beam[gcp] ?" shall I understand that the VM from which I launch the dataflow pipeline also has a role in its execution? What is its role during execution?
Because I was able to run the pipeline with DirectRunner on that VM, I would expect that it has all necessary packets?
I will install the library on VM and try again. Thank you.

Comment: @crbl Indeed, the local execution of the code creates the pipeline steps, and then send it for execution to a Runner. The runner can be DirectRunner or DataflowRunner or more.

Comment: @crbl you might also need to install Google's [cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk)

Answer (score 0):

In the versions before Beam 2.50.0, When DataflowRunner is used, Apache Beam Python SDK before launching the dataflow pipeline, downloads the `apache-beam` package from pypi on to your local and then stages it on the to the staging location provided by you.

For DataflowRunner v2 this is not needed because the default container the dataflow uses contains the apache_beam installation but the DataflowRunner v1 needs the staged packaged because apache_beam ins not installed on the default container that DataflowRunner v1 uses.

With Beam 2.50.0, Runner v1 is deprecated.

So for your case, I would suggest upgrade your beam version to 2.50.0 or use DataflowRunner v2 by passing `--experiments=use_runner_v2 --sdk_location=container`.

If you are already using runner v2 or runner v2 is auto enabled for you, you can just pass `--sdk_location=container`

Comment: @vdolez I created a virtual env and installed wheel and apache-beam[gcp]
Now I receive a different and very strange error. No matter which unique name I use for the job_name, the error is:
"apache_beam.runners.dataflow.internal.apiclient.DataflowJobAlreadyExistsError: There is already active job named pipeline_unique_name with id: ppline_unique_id. If you want to submit a second job, try again by setting a different name using --job_name." I will update the main post.

Comment: did you provide a job_name when launching a dataflow pipeline? if you try to launch a second dataflow pipeline with the same job name, the pipeline won't get launched. What is the unique name that are you providing? there are some restrictions on the job name should be specified, for example, underscores, capital letters not allowed. Try removing `job_name` from the cmd args when you launch a dataflow pipeline.

Comment: I solved the problem. When using "With" statement, the pipeline.run() command is not needed. This was not made very obvious in the documentation.

Comment: Please look at https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#creating-a-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. When using "With" statement, the pipeline.run() command is not needed.

Comment: I was having the same issue. This worked, by commenting out the `pipeline.run()` command